# Trouble configuring Apache virtual hosts in ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apache2, webserver, hosting

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.2 Updated to the latest and greatest

SO here's what I've don so far:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo nano mysite
```

Inside this file I've written the following definition:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
ServerName subdomain.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

then enabled the site with the following command(as root):

```
a2ensite mysite
```

then

```
service apache2 restart
```

all this to no avail. any suggestions?

EDIT: If there is more information I can add or things I can change to make getting a response more probable please let me know. thanks

Comment: After enabling the site:

root@KAL33K0-KORE:/etc/apache2/sites-available# nano mysite
root@KAL33K0-KORE:/etc/apache2/sites-available# a2ensite mysite
Enabling site mysite.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
root@KAL33K0-KORE:/etc/apache2/sites-available# service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server config apache2                                          [Thu Apr 18 21:40:30 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Comment: can someone explain?

http://sp2hari.com/apache-fix-namevirtualhost-80-has-no-virtualhosts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove NameVirtualHost *:80 from your virtual host's file.  This is already in /etc/apache2/ports.conf by default.

I placed NameVirtualHost *:80 in one of my virtual host's files and can confirm that I got the same error.

Comment: Just want to take a moment to sincerely thank you. It's hard to "learn by doing" when answers are scarce. So thank you. your helping me learn and move my project forward I am forever grateful to you for that!